# how to make one field value be equal to another field value in the same table by using django orm?

Tags: django, orm

In mysql, the sql expression is below:

```
udpate table set one_field=another_field
```

So how to make it success by using django orm? for example:

In model A, there are 3 fields: id, a_value
In model B, there are 3 fields: id, b_value
Now I want the value of b_value is equal to a_value plus b_value. the expression should be like this: `b_value = b_value + a_value`. But F() in the django orm can not be used in different models. How can I do this by using django orm in less code. 
By the way, my data is a little bigger, about 2000k.

Answer (score 3):

> For the original question:

```
for obj in Model_Name.objects.all():
    obj.one_field = obj.another_field
    obj.save()
```

If you have a large database you can use bulk updates. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#updating-multiple-objects-at-once

Hope this helps

Comment: thanks. I think F is what I want. My data is very big.

Comment: but in the document, it says: If you attempt to introduce a join with an F() object, a FieldError will be raised. When I update my field, it use other table's field value.Is there something else better to resolve this problem?Thanks.

Comment: Basically, with F(), you can update only those fields which are in one django model. As long as, "one_field" and "another_field" are both in same model,F() will work. But,if you are trying to update "one_field" which is in "Model_1" based on the value of "another_field in "Model_2", then F() won't work, because it doesn't support joins.Then you may have to use the approach that I have suggested in the answer.

Comment: hi, I update my question. By using `for obj in Model_Name.objects.all():
    obj.one_field = obj.another_field
    obj.save()` this code, it is not good for the big data, it can cause the memory is down.

Comment: I would suggest you to do with the approach that I suggested. I couldn't find enough time to do more research on it. Will help you out once I get some time

Comment: thanks a lot. I use paginator in django to resovle this problem. the paginator can handle the big data to some pieces of small data, then the memory is used smaller than before.